# List posts from categories in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch categories and posts associated to them but i can only retrieve category names from the DB and can't link them to their related posts, here's my code:

```
    <?php

    //Create DB object
    $db = new Database();

  //Check url got Category
    if(isset($_GET['categories'])){
      $category = $_GET['categories'];

      // Create Query
      $query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE category =". $category."ORDER BY id DESC";
      //Run query
      $posts = $db->select($query);
    }

    else{
        // Create Query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC";
        //Run query
        $posts = $db->select($query);
    }

  // Create Query
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  //Run query
  $categories = $db->select($query);

 ?>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main" style="width: 100%;">
        <?php if ($categories) : ?>
          <?php while($row = $categories->fetch_assoc()) : ?>

          <div class="blog-post">
            <h2 class="blog-post-title"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h2>

          </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>
          <p>There are no posts.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

and my DB tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: HINT:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the helpful hint :) can you give more insight on how it should be?

Comment: There is many things to improve in you code but mainly where do you loop over $posts ?

Comment: @phpguy . . . Let me be more clear.  If you are going to *use* SQL, you should *learn* SQL.  Asking random questions is not the right way.  There are plenty of resources -- tutorials, courses, books.  `JOIN` is such a basic part of SQL that not knowing it means that you can't use SQL correctly.